# Are terminations necessary for unused SuperSpeed signals in a USB-C 2.0 device port?

Tags: usb-c

We implemented a USB 2.0 device using the USB-C socket. It means just the D+, D-, VBUS/GND, and CC pins are connected.
Is it necessary or recommended to terminate the SuperSpeed pins somehow, or should they be left floating?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unused USB-3 signals should be left floating. In fact, unused USB-3 signals *must not* be terminated.

USB 3 detects the presence of a receiver by checking whether there's a 45-ohm termination resistor to ground (this resistor is usually inside the silicon of a USB 3 chip). This is done by sending detection pulses periodically and measuring the RC time constant of the signal. If a termination is detected, the host starts link training and negotiation according to the Low Frequency Periodic Signaling (LFPS) protocol.

If you terminate the SSTX signal (SSRX on the device connector) on an unused USB 3 port, if you're basically fooling the host into thinking that there's a USB 3.0 receiver attached. The host will try establishing a link endlessly in a futile attempt. This is not good. I haven't rechecked the USB standards so I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect too many failures may even cause the controller to disable this USB 3 port.

The full procedure explained in *Section 6.11 - Receiver Detection* section of the USB 3 specification.

> **6.11.1 Rx Detect Overview**: The Receiver Detection circuit is implemented as part of a Transmitter and must correctly detect whether a load impedance equivalent to a DC impedance R_RX-DC (Table 6-13) is present. The Rx detection operates on the principle of the RC time constant of the circuit. This time constant changes based on the presence of the receiver termination. This is conceptually illustrated in Figure 6-23. In this figure, R_Detect is the implementation specific charging resistor. C_AC is the AC capacitor that is in the circuit only if R_Term is also present, otherwise, only C_Parasitic is present.
> [image: Figure 6-23. Rx Detect Schematic]

Answer (score 1):

Think about a USB A plug that carrier USB 3. What happens when it is plugged into a USB 2 port? the SS pins float in the plug.

Likewise, I beleive SS pins can be left unconnected if unused. Any USB 3 devices connected will work via USB 2 mode.